# sonata don't show edit roules in dashboard

Tags: symfony, dashboard, sonata

i'm a newbie of sonata, i configure in this way my config.yml

sonata_admin:
    title: Name
    templates:
        layout:  SonataAdminBundle::layout.html.twig

```
dashboard:
    groups:
        PartnerShop:
            label: Partner Shop
            icon: <i class="fa fa-car"></i>
            items:
                - admin.content
                - admin.access
                - admin.category

        PagineComuni:
            label: Pagine Comuni
            icon: <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            items:
                - route: 'admin_app_comuni_edit'
                  route_params: { id: 1 } 
                  label: Name
                - route: 'admin_app_comuni_edit'
                  route_params: { id: 2 }
                  label: Brands
                - route: 'admin_app_comuni_edit'
                  route_params: { id: 3 } 
                  label: Gamma
                - route: 'admin_app_comuni_edit'
                  route_params: { id: 4 }
                  label: Logistica

        User:
           label: Utenti
           icon: <i class="fa fa-users"></i>
           items:
                - sonata.user.admin.user
                - sonata.user.admin.group
           roles: [ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN ]
```

in side menù all it works, i see the correct list of admin, but in dashboard i see only the ParnerShop and User block, PagineComuni is not present

exist a way to display pagine comuni beetween ParnerShop and User?

thank you